# books on Continuous-time markov chains

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, book-recommendation, markov-process

I am looking for a books on continuous time markov chains. The books should include:

> -Conditions and proofs of what is necessary for there to be a finite number of transitions in every interval.
>
> -The formula and its proof for the expected number of transitions from a given state to another in an interval.
>
> -And also the formula for the expected value of  $$\int_0^T f(t)dN_{ij}(t,\omega)$$, where f is an integrable function and and
>   $dN_{ij}(t,\omega)$ is 1 if we have a jump from $i$ to $j$ at time t
>   and zero if not.

Do you know about any books that will cover these topics? It doesn't have to be in only one book.

Comment: That is a very particular list of requirements and I think you would be best off searching references for each of them individually. I can't think of a book off the top of my head that would necessary prove each of these statements.

Comment: @Math1000 Thank you. I wouldn't min it beeing different references for each part.

Comment: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387002118 This text covers the first part, as I recall.